# Android - Stream audio from all running apps

Tags: android, audio, redirect, stream

Is there a way to stream/redirect all current playing audio on android phone to server?
By all I mean audio from all currently running apps.

Answer (score 1):

Your application has no right to interfere with the audio playback from another application.

With custom firmware, this may be possible, but not from an ordinary SDK application.

Comment: Why has no right? There is nothing wrong with processing audio from another app.

Comment: This, sadly, makes implementing airfoil or something similar impossible :(